# Casting ArrayList<SuperClass> to ArrayList<SubClass>

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I know it sounds dumb, but I really need it.
I'm 100% positive about only allowing SubClass into the arraylist. No other subclass of SuperClass is in that arraylist.

How can I do this?

```
    Map<String, List<Nodo>> map = ((Cast to ArrayList<NodoMoore> here)nodos).stream().
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Nodo::getSalida));
```

My class implements an interface that makes me use Nodo instead of NodoMoore, but the getSalida method is not a Nodo method, only a NodoMoore method.

Comment: Can you show us a few skeleton class definitions that would help us replicate what you're seeing?  Also, which class is implementing the interface?

Comment: Can you map first, eg map a Nodo -> a NodoMoore with a cast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using a method handle (`Nodo::getSalida`), you can use a lambda and do the cast there instead:

```
Map<String, List<Nodo>> map = nodos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x->((NodoMoore)x).getSalida());
```

Comment: Amazing, I had no idea I could do this. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this answer and Eran's answer have different return types. You'd pick one approach or the other based on your desired return type.

Comment: This was the desired output. I couldn't work with List<NodoMoore> because of the interface.

Answer (score 8):

If you are sure that `nodos` contains only instances of `NodoMoore`,
you can map the `Nodo` instances to `NodoMoore` instances with a cast :

```
Map<String, List<NodoMoore>> map = 
    nodos.stream()
         .map(n->(NodoMoore)n)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NodoMoore::getSalida));
```

I assumed that `NodoMoore` is a sub-class of `Nodo`.

Comment: Hello, DaoWen's answer has the output I want but this is also a very useful answer.

Comment: A in my opinion slightly more elegant solutiin would be to use `nodos.stream().map(NodoMoore.class::cast).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NodoMoore::getSalida))`, because it's better readable.

Comment: Hello, I'm new to this "::" thing. Why is it more elegant?

Comment: `NodoMoore.class::cast` is equal to `p -> NodoMoore.class.cast(p)`. Using the `::`-operator, you are implicitly either filling the parameters of the method or, if the method is non-static but supplied without an instance, giving the instance the method should run on. E.g. `FooFactory::createFrom` vs. `Foo::toString`.

Comment: Ups, i got drifted slightly away from your question. It's more elegant, because it's more readable, even for non-Java geeks.